# Does the stable version of Debian contain a vulnerable version of wpa_supplicant?

Tags: debian, security, package-management

I'm on Debian jessie the stable release. I noticed that version of  `wpa_supplicant` is vulnerable to DoS attacks according to [CVE-2015-8041](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-8041):

> Multiple integer overflows in the NDEF record parser in hostapd before 2.5 and wpa_supplicant before 2.5 allow remote attackers to cause a denial of service (process crash or infinite loop) via a large payload length field value in an (1) WPS or (2) P2P NFC NDEF record, which triggers an out-of-bounds read.

On the stable release  the available version is `wpa_supplicant 2.3`, with a regular `sources.list` it's not possible to upgrade the current version to  `wpa_supplicant 2.5` , Why does Debian stable keep some obsolete (vulnerable) packages?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Debian has security tracker which shows status of the CVE's in all supported releases. Here is your:

https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2015-8041

You can check it is fixed in version `2.3-1+deb8u3`. The fix was probably  backported to the older version, which prevents breaking other things with rebase to new version in stable release (point of stable release).

Comment: Amusing naming. If there were a release called 2.3-1+deb8u9, I'd think it just a debug release that somehow got into production.

Comment: Deb in this place is from Debian and not from Debug :-)

Answer (score 2):

A bug that allow a remote individual to crash the software (DoS) isn't exactly at the same level of risk as what we normally think of when we talk about "vulnerabilities".  I wouldn't call this a "vulnerable" package; otherwise, you're elevating any bug that can cause the program to crash to a security "vulnerability".

Also, it's not clear to me whether this is actually exploitable on any real Debian system.  See the comments in https://w1.fi/security/2015-5/incomplete-wps-and-p2p-nfc-ndef-record-payload-length-validation.txt and http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2015/11/02/5:

> Note: No NFC stack implementation has yet been identified with
>   capability to pass the malformed NDEF record to
>   hostapd/wpa_supplicant. As such, it is not known whether this issue can
>   be triggered in practice.

As always, security is about risk management.  The level of risk due to this bug sounds pretty low to me.

Comment: This is certainly a good point to note that it might not be so serious issue in someone's sight. And this is why we have possibility to update or not, when we type `apt-get upgrade`.